# Equivalente a função sql LEFT() no JPA

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

Qual a função equivalente a LEFT() no JPA?

Preciso pegar somente os 6 primeiros caracteres de um campo.

O select equivalente em *sql* seria:

```
select  left(campo,6), count(*) qtd
from tabela
group by left(campo,6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não existe função LEFT() no jpa!

A documentação restringe a captura de porções de string somente à [função] SUBSTRING().

ex:

```
select substring(v.campo, 1, 6), count(*)
from V v
group by substring(v.campo, 1, 6)
```